# Replace numbers in a file name in unix (BASH)

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, rename

I have multiple files approximately 150 and there names do not match a requirement of a vendor. example file names are:

```
company_red001.p12 
company_red002.p12
.
.
.
.
company_red150.p12
```

I need to rename all files so that 24 is added to each number sequentially and that there are no preceding zero's and that the company_ component is removed.

```
red25.p12
red26.p12
red27.p12
.
.
.
red150.p12
```

I have used a *for* loop in bash to remove the *company_* component but would like something that executes all changes simultaneously as I have to perform this at a moments notice.

example:

```
#!/bin/bash

n = 24

for file in company_red*

do

  new_name=$file$n
  n=$(($+1))
  mv -i $file $new_name

done
```

example 2

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in company_red*

do mv "$f" "${f/company_red/red}";

done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.. `I have used a for loop in..` - Please provide the code samples in question to show at least some effort from your part :)

Comment: My apologies this was done on my work computer and I cannot verbatim produce my efforts, the sample above did not work.

Comment: Thank you all, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably this one could be fine :)

```
# printf is used to emulate a lot of files
for f in $( printf "company_red%03d.p12\n" {1..150} )
do
    # get the filename
    n="$f"
    # remove extension
    n="${n%.*}"
    # remove leading letters
    n="${n##*[[:alpha:]]}"
    # add 24, 10# is used to consider the 10-based number
    n="$(( 10#$n + 24 ))"
    # construct new filename
    g="red${n}.p12"
    echo mv "$f" "$g"
done
```

And this could be simplified a bit

```
for f in $( printf "company_red%03d.p12\n" {1..150} )
do
    # take the number from the specific, fixed position
    n="${f:11:3}"
    # everything below is the same as in the previous example
    n="$(( 10#$n + 24 ))"
    g="red${n}.p12"
    echo mv "$f" "$g"
done
```

And finally, this could be simplified yet twice -- just escape of using `$n` and `$g`:

```
for f in $( printf "company_red%03d.p12\n" {1..150} )
do
    echo mv "$f" "red$(( 10#${f:11:3} + 24 )).p12"
done
```

But this could complicate understanding and supporting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
for file in *.p12; do 
    name=${file#*_}  ## Extracts the portion after `_` from filename, save as variable "name"
    pre=${name%.*}  ## Extracts the portion before extension, save as "pre"
    num=${pre##*[[:alpha:]]}  ## Extracts number from variable "pre"
    pre=${pre%%[0-9]*}  ## Extracts the alphabetic portion from variable "pre"
    suf=${name##*.}  ## Extracts the extension from variable "name"
        echo mv -i "$file" "${pre}""$(printf '%d' $((10#$num+24)))"."${suf}"  ## Doing arithmetic expansion for addition, and necessary formatting to get desired name
done
```

Outputs:

```
mv -i company_red001.p12 red25.p12
mv -i company_red002.p12 red26.p12
```

The above is dry-run, remove `echo` if you are satisfied with the renaming to be done:

```
for file in *.p12; do 
    name=${file#*_}
    pre=${name%.*}
    num=${pre##*[[:alpha:]]}
    pre=${pre%%[0-9]*}
    suf=${name##*.}
        mv -i "$file" "${pre}""$(printf '%d' $((10#$num+24)))"."${suf}"
done
```